# How do I collect values from dynamically created text fields?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a react app and have dynamically built text fields for input based on an array of changing variables. How do I collect the value input for each field since it's not hard coded?

```
  const [elementVariables, setElementVariables] = useState([]);
  const [dataCollect, setDataCollect] = useState([]);

  const handleVariableChange = (e) => {
     console.log('variable value: ', e.target.value)
     setDataCollect(e.target.value);
  }

  <div>
    <Divider />
    {elementVariables.map((item) => (
      <TextField
        key={item}
        label={item}
        className={props.classes.textField}
        value={dataCollect}
        onChange={e => handleVariableChange(e)}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dataCollect needs to be an array and the textField value needs to include the index.

The handleVariableChange needs to update the original array with the updated value from the textField.

```
    const [elementVariables, setElementVariables] = useState([]);
    const [dataCollect, setDataCollect] = useState([]);

    const handleVariableChange = (e, index) => {
      const newArr = [...dataCollect]
      newArr[index] = e.target.value;
      setDataCollect(newArr);
    }


    {elementVariables.map((item, index) => (
      <TextField
        key={item}
        label={item}
        value={dataCollect[index] || ''}
        onChange={e => handleVariableChange(e, index)}
      />
    ))}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am doing this using the index argument that map provides
but you could also use some property within the item object which has a unique value,the 'id' property.Updated the answer to have the correct value prop based upon the index key.

```
const [elementVariables, setElementVariables] = useState([]);
  const [dataCollect, setDataCollect] = useState({}); //use an object.

  const handleVariableChange = (e,index) => {
     console.log('variable value: ', e.target.value)
     setDataCollect((dataCollect)=>({...dataCollect,[index]:e.target.value})); 
     /* will result in an object with keys representing text fields 
        {0:'value 1',1:'value2'}
         }
     */

  <div>
    <Divider />
    {elementVariables.map((item,index) => (
      <TextField
        key={item}
        label={item}
        className={props.classes.textField}
        value={dataCollect[index]?dataCollect[index]:''}
        onChange={e => handleVariableChange(e,index)}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
```

Comment: It's not working yet... I believe dataCollect needs to be an array of objects as there are sometimes multiple text fields. Also, value={dataCollect} is causing errors.

Comment: Should value={dataCollect}  be something like value={dataCollect[index].value?  That doesn't work though...

Comment: value = dataCollect[index]?dataCollect[index]:'' ,meaning if the key exists then take the value otherwise empty string

Comment: I'm getting error: "Cannot read property 'value' of null" on the setDataCollect line

Comment: Is the console.log  line printing e.target.value ?... coz then it exists for the setDataColect line also

Comment: I found the solution - see answer.  Thank you for helping with this!